# is it possible to set up multiple ssids using rpi 3?

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I have been trying to setup multiple ssid configuration in my rpi 3B so that my rpi can broadcast multiple ssid through the adapter present in the stock hardware itself. Does BCM43143 support it?

Answer (score 3):

You asked "*can a Raspberry Pi broadcast multiple ssid through the adapter present in the stock hardware itself?*". The SSID is a unique identifier for a WiFi network broadcasted by an access point. You cannot have multiple SSIDs for the same WiFi network. So I assume that you mean if you can have multiple WiFi networks (access points) from one Raspberry Pi. You can find with:

```
rpi ~$ iw list
--- snip ---
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
       total <= 3, #channels <= 2
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
       total <= 4, #channels <= 1
--- snip ---
```

As shown with `#{ AP } <= 1` it is only possible to have one access point.

So the answer to your question is: no, you cannot have multiple SSID from the built-in wireless device. If you need that you have to use additional USB/WiFi dongle.